# Basis for polynomial subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_{3}$ be the vector space of all real polynomials of degree at most 3. The sets U, V $\subseteq$ $P_{3}$ are defined by

$U$ = {$p$ $\in$ $P_{3}$: p(1) = p(2) = 0} and $V$ = {$p$ $\in$ $P_{3}$: p(1) = p(3) = 0}

Describe the bases for $U$, $V$ and $U$ $\cap$ $V$.

**Attempted solution**

$U$ = {$(x-1)(x-2)p(x)$: $p(x)$ $\in$ $P_{1}$}

which means $p(x)$ is of the form:

$p(x)$ = $a_{0}$ + $a_{1}x$

expanding the polynomial in $U$, I get:

$q(x)$ = $a_{0}(x-1)(x-2)$ + $a_{1}x(x-1)(x-2)$

would the basis for $U$ simply be: {$(x-1)(x-2)$, $x(x-1)(x-2)$} and if true, will the procedure be similar for $V$ and $U$ $\cap$ $V$?

Comment: Yes, this looks correct to me.